# Will localstorage automatically fall to cookies in old browser?

Tags: jquery, cookies, local-storage

It is said that localstorage only supported by browsers newer than this:

- IE 8
- Firefox 3.5
- Safari 4
- Chrome 4
- Opera 10.5
- iOS 2.0
- Android 2.0

So, if I my clients will use older browser - is it OK for me to store some information (less than 4kb) still in localstorage via jquery?

Also, which mobile browsers support localstorage?

Comment: This is the kind of thing you ask our friend Google, not Stack Overflow :)

Comment: "Will localstorage automatically fall to cookies in old browser?" No is the answer but you can use polyfill

Comment: Also, you can do a simple check for localStorage and fallback to cookies in your own code.  Just write get and set functions and make them check

Comment: _which browser supports localstorage?_ [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) - _will localstorage automatically fall to cookies?_ [fallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

Comment: @Archer Unless Google tells us to look into StackOverflow

Comment: @OverCoder - we're not here to spoon feed.  We're here to help people who have tried and failed.  This is a feeding request, so not relevant to SO.

Answer (score 4):

Just do a simple test to see if it's supported:

```js
if("localStorage" in window)
    //localstorage supported
```

or simply

```js
if(localStorage)
    //localstorage supported
```

It won't help if you use a jQuery plugin. It will still boil down to whether if it's supported by the browser or not.

Answer (score 1):

NO. The old browsers don't know what to do with local storage. Local storage was initially defined as part of the HTML5 standard but now has been moved to a different one.

What you can do is use something like [PersistJs](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557) and/or use a feature detection library (read Modernizr).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Okay, guys:) My question was mostly about 'will jquery automatically store data in cookies if there are no localstorage'. So, it turns out that it will not becouse it is very different mechanisms.

Also, according to [this](http://www.quora.com/localStorage/How-well-supported-is-localstorage-across-mobile-devices):

```
Local storage is available on all the modern appphones and has been for a while. 

iOS 3.2 and above
Android 2.1 and above
RIM OS 6 and above

It's NOT available on Windows Phone 7 or Opera Mini (since it's not a real local browser)
```

And [there](https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/4718380) are the code to automatically choose supported storage for your data.

Comment: Like I said in my answer. persistjs is the answer you are looking for.